# DispatcherTimer waiting in for loop

Tags: c#, wpf, dispatcher

I want load a picture every few seconds. I create DispatcherTimer and I want in timer tick do nothing, just waiting interval. How can I do that?

```
if (window.DialogResult == true) {
                st=window.st;
                for(int i=0;i<=st;i++){
                    timer = new DispatcherTimer();
                    timer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0,0,5);
                    timer.Tick += new EventHandler(timer_Tick);
                    timer.Start();
                arr[i]=window.arr[i];
                image1.Source = arr[i];
                }
            }
```

And here I have for now empty tick.

```
void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
```

Comment: Are you sure that's what you want? Or do you want to load an image on each tick? Currently you are creating many `DispatcherTimer`objects to do nothing ...

Comment: @WolfgangZiegler yeah, I checking options with DispatcherTimer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One option is to use `async`/`await`:

```
async void button_click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // prepare the array
    // ...

    for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        image1.Source = arr[i];
        await Task.Delay(5000);
    }
}
```

You may want to make to make sure `button_click` is not re-entered while the asynchronous loop is still iterating. Check Lucian Wishick's ["Async re-entrancy, and the patterns to deal with it".](https://web.archive.org/web/20140716063738/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/lucian/archive/2014/03/03/async-re-entrancy-and-the-patterns-to-deal-with-it.aspx)

If you insist on using `DispatcherTimer`:

```
async void button_click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // prepare the array
    // ...

    var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<object>();
    var timer = new DispatcherTimer();
    timer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0,0,5);
    timer.Tick += (_, __) => tcs.SetResult(Type.Missing);
    timer.Start();
    try
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            image1.Source = arr[i];
            await tcs.Task;
            tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<object>();
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        timer.Stop();
    }
}
```

Comment: with DispatcherTimer I can't made same effect?